# cocos2d-x - Apply blur to transparent LayerColor

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I have investigated how the blur shader is applied to sprite in tests of `cocos2d-x` (`ShaderTest/ShaderTest2.cpp`).

Now my problem is a bit different: I have a layer initialized as follows:

```
LayerColor::initWithColor(Color4B(0, 0, 0, 180)
```

So it is black but transparent. My intention is to show the content under the layer but with bad visibility.

Now I need to add a blur effect to make visibility under my `ColorLayer` even worse.

My first question is how I can do that? 
The second why `cocos2d-x` does not support such simple and vastly used effects such blur is without using shaders?

P.S. I use`cocos2d-x 3.0`.

Comment: does this help: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/53167

Comment: @GameDeveloper thanks for the link. But I know how to blur a texture, it is done in cocos2d-x test by applying a shader. My problem is to blur what is visible under a transparent LayerColor.

Comment: blur the whole layer underneath at once? or just blur part of the layer underneath?

Comment: Blur color layer so that everything underneath was blured too. Another solution is to blur everything underneath and also apply transparent `ColorLayer`.